# Android AOSP 5.1 disable/remove wifi proxy

Tags: android, proxy, wifi, android-source

I am new to Android AOSP/ Android platform. We are using MTK based chipset with Android 5.1 version.  I have a task to disable/remove the proxy option when we use WiFi -> tap on SSID -> Modify network -> Tap Manual settings -> Modify proxy (None, Manual, Auto-Settings).  Please provide some pointers to disable or at least gray out the proxy from UI.

Does the disabling "policylab_setGlobalProxy" flag in strings.xml has any effect on this feature?

Thanks,
Sai

Answer (score 1):

Modify the class showing that UI. Basically change the visibility or remove those views....

Searching a bit on androidxref, I think it's WifiController in Settings:
http://androidxref.com/5.1.1_r6/xref/packages/apps/Settings/src/com/android/settings/wifi/WifiConfigController.java#showProxyFields

Comment: Thanks for the help Rick and Team.. By using the below lines (in showProxyFields() ) we are able remove the proxy settings in WIFi UI.                                                                                                                 mView.findViewById(R.id.proxy_settings_fields).setEnabled(false);                                                                                
(Or)            
mView.findViewById(R.id.proxy_settings_fields).setVisibility(View.GONE);

Comment: Yayy. Glad I could be of help :) Don't forget to accept the answer then.